# Noise on PWM before connecting to buck circuit

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, noise, mosfet-driver, supercapacitor

I have built a buck converter in the circuit configuration below in order to charge a supercapacitor. The PWM signal is being applied with an arduino and is in the place of the signal generator in the image. [image: sas]The problem is that the PWM signal from the arduino is highly distorted after it is connected to the circuit. I have attached pictures of the PWM before it is connected and after. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PWM before connected to circuit[image]

PWM when connected to circuit
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The return path of the converter gets "dirty" while the converter is operating, because of switching high currents and presence of inductors, leakage inductances, parasitic capacitances etc.. And you are carrying those dirt into Arduino's signal path via shorting GND lines of both.

The first thing I can recommend is putting a snubber across Q1 so that the dirt caused by ringing can be wasted. You have an oscilloscope, so calculating the values of snubber is your job. And remember, Google is your friend.

And the last thing I can recommend is putting a ferrite filter between signal ground (ie Arduino's GND) and power ground (ie converter's GND) so that they are shorted in terms of DC and isolated in terms of AC. You can also put the same filter between Arduino's PWM output and converter's PWM input.

About the filters: You can find 1206 case SMD ones having 500mA current rating. Search on Würth's website.

Answer (score 1):

Put some gate resistance alse you will soon burn the driver IC. The ringing could be also the artifact of gate resistance less operation.

Connect the two grounds 12V and 5V in one single point. Don't let the current flows back and forth over that connecting point.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIFVR0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>